# Копирование в буфер с помощью jQuery.

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Мне нужна HTML-страница, на которой было бы что-то вроде того, что [тут](http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/) справа.

Желательно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку 1, копировалось значение 1, и так далее.

Пожалуйста, помогите!
Я не знаю как, что и куда вставлять.

Comment: Плюс за живую ссылку по теме вопроса.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Елки-палки. По вашей ссылке всё написано! Читать умеем?
Качаем эту либу, потом смотрим что написано в Usage, включаем мозг, и радуемся!!!!